# How to shrink top and bottom margins equally but keep center menu consistent?

Tags: html, css, margins

**Please refer to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HadA9.png).** It'll make things much easier to understand, rather than looking at the code.

I'm trying to design a menu that will always be at the exact center of the page.

The menu should only shrink once the margins have completely disappeared. 

At first it seemed rather simple, but to my dismay, I learned that CSS will try to compress the menu and the margins into a small area when shrinking the page.

```css
body, html
{
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent browser from displaying scroll-bars */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;

  /* Force the HTML and Body to fill entire window */
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
}

/* Removes margins and padding on all HTML-CSS elements.  */
/* This is so that we don't run into any unecessary whitespace during website design*/
body, html, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div.Top-Margin
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
  background-color: orange; /* TODO: visibility purposes, only for TESTING */
  height: 25%;
}

div.Center-Margin
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  background-color: pink; /* TODO: visibility purposes, only for TESTING */
  height: 50%;
}

div.Bottom-Margin
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
  background-color: yellow; /* TODO: Visibility purposes, only for TESTING */
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

/* Consistent style between desktop and mobile*/
div.Menu-Container
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes rainbow-border
{
  0%   {border-color: #ff0000;}
  10%  {border-color: #ff8000;}
  20%  {border-color: #ffff00;}
  30%  {border-color: #80ff00;}
  40%  {border-color: #00ff00;}
  50%  {border-color: #00ff80;}
  60%  {border-color: #00ffff;}
  70%  {border-color: #0080ff;}
  80%  {border-color: #0000ff;}
  90%  {border-color: #8000ff;}
  100% {border-color: #ff0080;}
}

/*---------------*/
/*---------------*/
/* The side navigation menu */
div.Menu-Options
{
  margin-top: 416.5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Menu Buttons Content */
div.Menu-Options a
{
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Active Menu Button */
div.Menu-Options a.suggested
{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Inactive Menu Buttons: Hover */
div.Menu-Options a:hover:not(.suggested)
{
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/*---------------*/
/*---------------*/

@media screen
{
  div.Menu-Container
  {
    /* Menu size remains consistent with page size */
    width:  300px;
    height: 621.5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    /* Border-Style */
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-style: dashed;
    border-left-style: dashed;

    animation: rainbow-border 2s infinite;
    border-color: #00ffff; /* Required incase browser does not support animated border */
    border-width: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-desktop.css">
    <title>Pacman-Esque: Main Menu</title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div class=Top-Margin>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class=Center-Margin>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class=Bottom-Margin>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>


    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <div class=Menu-Container>
      <div class=Animated-Logo>
        <!-- Will contain animated logo -->
      </div>
      <!-- Menu Options -->
      <div class=Menu-Options>
        <a class="suggested" href="#">Start Game</a>
        <a href="#">Highscores</a>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Turns out I didn't even need any `Bottom-Margin`, `Top-Margin` HTML div elements. 

All I needed to do was add the following code to my `Menu-Container`:

```
  /* Aligns menu to center of page */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Thank you for all your answers!

```css
/* Group:........ That Helvetica Group
 * Members:...... Scott McKay, Kendyl Freeny, William Cook
 * Institution:.. University of Montana
 * Class:........ Advanced Web Design & Programming
 * Date:......... Friday, October 12th, 2018
*/

/*............... Cascading Style Sheet for Menu UI ...............*/


body, html
{
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent browser from displaying scroll-bars */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;

  /* Force the HTML and Body to fill entire window */
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
}

/* Removes margins and padding on all HTML-CSS elements.*/
/* This is so that we don't run into any unecessary whitespace during website design*/
body, html, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div.Menu-Container
{
  /* Aligns menu to center of page */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /* Dimensions of the menu-container */
  width:  300px;
  height: 621.5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  /* Border-Style */
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-right-style: dashed;
  border-left-style: dashed;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #00ffff; /* Required incase browser does not support animated border */
  animation:rainbow-border 2s infinite;

  /* Container Shadow */
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/* List of Alternating Colors in Border */
@keyframes rainbow-border
{
  0%   {border-color: #ff0000;}
  10%  {border-color: #ff8000;}
  20%  {border-color: #ffff00;}
  30%  {border-color: #80ff00;}
  40%  {border-color: #00ff00;}
  50%  {border-color: #00ff80;}
  60%  {border-color: #00ffff;}
  70%  {border-color: #0080ff;}
  80%  {border-color: #0000ff;}
  90%  {border-color: #8000ff;}
  100% {border-color: #ff0080;}
}

/* The side navigation menu */
div.Menu-Options
{
  margin-top: 416.5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Sidebar links */
div.Menu-Options a
{
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Active/current link */
div.Menu-Options a.suggested
{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Links on mouse-over */
div.Menu-Options a:hover:not(.suggested)
{
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!--
Group:........ That Helvetica Group
Members:...... Scott McKay, Kendyl Freeny, William Cook
Institution:.. University of Montana
Class:........ Advanced Web Design & Programming
Date:......... Friday, October 12th, 2018
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-desktop.css">
    <title>Pacman-Esque: Main Menu</title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <div class=Menu-Container>
      <div class=Animated-Logo>
        <!-- Will contain animated logo -->
      </div>
      <!-- Menu Options -->
      <div class=Menu-Options>
        <a class="suggested" href="#">Start Game</a>
        <a href="#">Highscores</a>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This will stop borders from resizing elements.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have misunderstood the usage of absolute positioning in CSS here. Absolutely positioned element is computed (top,left,bottom,right) from the edges of the element's containing block. The containing block here is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.
More clear explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning

```html
<html><head>
    <style>
        body, html
{
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent browser from displaying scroll-bars */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;

  /* Force the HTML and Body to fill entire window */
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
}

/* Removes margins and padding on all HTML-CSS elements.  */
/* This is so that we don't run into any unecessary whitespace during website design*/
body, html, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div.Top-Margin
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
  background-color: orange; /* TODO: visibility purposes, only for TESTING */
  height: 25%;
}

div.Center-Margin
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  background-color: pink; /* TODO: visibility purposes, only for TESTING */
  height: 50%;
}

div.Bottom-Margin
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
  background-color: yellow; /* TODO: Visibility purposes, only for TESTING */
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

/* Consistent style between desktop and mobile*/
div.Menu-Container
{
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 45%;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes rainbow-border
{
  0%   {border-color: #ff0000;}
  10%  {border-color: #ff8000;}
  20%  {border-color: #ffff00;}
  30%  {border-color: #80ff00;}
  40%  {border-color: #00ff00;}
  50%  {border-color: #00ff80;}
  60%  {border-color: #00ffff;}
  70%  {border-color: #0080ff;}
  80%  {border-color: #0000ff;}
  90%  {border-color: #8000ff;}
  100% {border-color: #ff0080;}
}

/*---------------*/
/*---------------*/
/* The side navigation menu */
div.Menu-Options
{
  /*margin-top: 416.5px;*/
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Menu Buttons Content */
div.Menu-Options a
{
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Active Menu Button */
div.Menu-Options a.suggested
{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Inactive Menu Buttons: Hover */
div.Menu-Options a:hover:not(.suggested)
{
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/*---------------*/
/*---------------*/

@media screen
{
  div.Menu-Container
  {
    /* Menu size remains consistent with page size */
    width:  300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    /* Border-Style */
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-style: dashed;
    border-left-style: dashed;

    animation: rainbow-border 2s infinite;
    border-color: #00ffff; /* Required incase browser does not support animated border */
    border-width: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
    </head>
<body>
    

  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-desktop.css">
    <title>Pacman-Esque: Main Menu</title>
  


  
    <div class="Top-Margin">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Center-Margin">
      <div class="Menu-Container">
      <div class="Animated-Logo">
        <!-- Will contain animated logo -->
      </div>
      <!-- Menu Options -->
      <div class="Menu-Options">
        <a class="suggested" href="#">Start Game</a>
        <a href="#">Highscores</a>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
    </div><p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Bottom-Margin">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>


    <!-- Main Menu -->
    
  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question seeing the other answers. But if you want the minimum size to stay at a certain % of the page, you can use the min-width property.

in this case I added

```
div.Menu-Container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 2;
    min-height: 50%;
    }
```

and it kept it at those margins when moved at different sizes.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have it so that the top and bottom margins will be the first things to disappear as the page shrinks. Both margins should be the same size at all times.  By default CSS will compress the margins. (compressing the bottom one more, and not making both them disappear). But thank you for reminding me about the `min-height:` option, that'll be useful as I tweak the website.